# Calling WCF BasicBinding service from .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

I have a WCF SOAP service on IIS that uses `basicHttpBinding` and is configured to require client certificate:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding>
    <readerQuotas/>
    <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"></transport>
    </security>
  </binding>             
</basicHttpBinding>
```

I have to call that service from .Net Core 3.1 app. Here is what I have:

```
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
    binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;

    ChannelFactory<PaymentRequestService> factory = new ChannelFactory<PaymentRequestService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(_apiOptions.Value.PaymentRequestServiceEndpoint)));
    factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = GetClientCertificate(certBase64, certPass); // X509Certificate2
    PaymentRequestService client = factory.CreateChannel();
    var rx = client.SavePaymentRequestAsync(myRequest);
```

When I check the factory in debug I see that client credential certificate (SHA256) is there, however it looks like the client credential doesn't reach the webservice, because I keep getting **The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'**

It makes no difference if I use `BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential` or set the certificate using `factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate()`

Any ideas?

Comment: Also I've read that .net core might silently reject some certificates (SHA1 or if it doesn't have certain EKU attributes) but I have no idea where to check if that is the case here.

Comment: This may be related to whether the client certificate has the EKU of ClientAuthentication, the link contains similar questions, you can refer to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489489/configuring-wcf-client-binding-to-use-x509-certificate-in-dotnet-core-2-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out starting with Windows Server 2012 you need to set `SendTrustedIssuerList` and `ClientAuthTrustMode` registry settings in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL

https://configmgrblog.com/2014/02/23/configmgr-2012-r2-internet-facing-mp-windows-server-2012-r2-note/